# Laravel multiple fields validation not working

Tags: php, laravel, forms, validation, laravel-formrequest

I'm trying to validate three input fields.

If the fields are null then the three fields are not mandatory, but If at least one of them is not empty (null) then all three should be mandatory. But It's doesn't working. If I leave all three fields blank It shows that the three fields are mandatory. It shoud allow the form to be submitted.

```
public function rules()
    {
      return [
        'a' => 'required_if:b,!=,null|required_if:c,!=,null',
        'b' => 'required_if:a,!=,null|required_if:c,!=,null',
        'c' => 'required_if:a,!=,null|required_if:b,!=,null',
      ];
    }
```

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a **[Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Comment: Have a look at required_with instead

Answer (score 0):

Dale suggests using `required_with` instead of `required_if`, however you can use [Preparing Input For Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#preparing-input-for-validation) it will do the trick.